# Как вывести несколько массивов из JSON в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, массивы, json

Если выгонять из базы по отдельности `ALLROOM` и `USERS` то всё работает `json[j].room` или `json[j].f` но вместе одним запросом не получается.
Как правильно вывести из одного кода только `ALLROOM` и отдельно `USERS` ?

Вывод по отдельности в PHP:

```
$pack[] = array('room'=>$row->room,'room2'=>$row->room2 );
echo json_encode($pack);
```

JSON отдельно `ALLROOM`:

```
[{"allroom":[{"room":"1"},{"room2":"2"}]
```

JSON отдельно `USERS`:

```
[{"users":[{"f":"admin1","l":"admin1"},{"f":"admin2","l":"admin2"}]}]
```

В PHP я их соединил так:

```
$pack[] = array('allroom'=>$room,'users'=>$users );  
echo json_encode($pack);
```

JSON сразу два `ALLROOM` и `USERS`:

```
[{"allroom":[{"room":"1"},{"room2":"2"}],"users":[{"f":"admin1","l":"admin1"},{"f":"admin2","l":"admin2"}]}]
```

Код в JS AJAX

```
 $.ajax({
       url: '/ajax/stats', 
        type: 'POST',
        data:({room: 1}), 
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(json) {
            var j = 0;
            while(j <= json.length-1){ 
            $('#stat_users').html(json);
            j++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `json[j].allroom`

Comment: обновил ответ, только что проверил, кажется то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/ajax/stats', 
    type: 'POST',
    data:({room: 1}), 
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(json) {
        for (var i in json.users){
           $('#stat_users').append(json.users[i]);
        }
        console.log(json.allroom); // повторить с allroom при надобности
    }
```

Comment: Пишет ошибку VM966:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: я кажется не проснулся, попробуйте так. JSON.parse похоже не нужен в вашем случае

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/ajax/stats', 
  type: 'POST',
  data:({room: 1}), 
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json[0].allroom.length; i++) {
      console.log(json[0].allroom[i].name);
      console.log(json[0].allroom[i].caption);
    }    
    for (var i = 0; i < json[0].users.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < json[0].users[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(json[0].users[i][j].type)
        console.log(json[0].users[i][j].name)
      }
    }       
  }
});
```

```html
// взял исходный массив и попытался изменить его по минимум, его нужно привести в такой вот вид:
$pack[] = array(
    'allroom' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'room1',
            'caption' => '1'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'room2',
            'caption' => '2'
        )
    ),
    'users' => array(
        array(
            array(
              'type' => 'f',
              'name' => 'admin1'
            ),
            array(
              'type' => 'l',
              'name' => 'admin1'
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
              'type' => 'f',
              'name' => 'admin2'
            ),
            array(
              'type' => 'l',
              'name' => 'admin2'
            )
        ),
    )
);

echo json_encode($pack);
```

Comment: пишет ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: в php файле вместо $pack[] = напишите $pack =, либо в переборе нужно будет писать так - json[0].allroom.length и соответственно json[0].allroom[i].room

Comment: Ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'f' of undefined
Вывожу щас один  $('#stat_users').append(json.users[j].f);

Comment: сразу после получения success: function(json) { напишите console.log(json) и покажите пожалуйста что у вас в Консоле браузера пришло от php скрипта

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13 - это с консоли

Comment: А строка также осталась без изменения? -  success: function(json)?

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что вы не правильно собираете массив в php.

Comment: Пример должен работать если массив будет собрана таким образом, надеюсь я правильно понял его структуру.